# How to conditional format each row of a column based on corresponding value in another column

Tags: google-sheets

Please refer the image
I want the cell to be highlighted based on the value is less than or greater than the  value in the benchmark column. I am not able to do that using conditional formatting custom formula. I have manually applied formatting for 02/01/2023 . I want the formatting to apply to the column with date = today() only.
Thanks :)

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

I can write a custom formula for each row of each date column. But is there any way a single custom formula that could format across rows and columns?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your fist value of 02/01/2023 and Activity1 is C2. Then for the whole range C2:Z (or whichever you have):

```
=C2>=$B2
```

Do this for one color for the whole range and it will drag automatically, you don't need to write it as an arrayformula. The "$" will always refer to the value in column B from the row it's positioned

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I  need another functionality too. What if I want to apply this conditional formatting for current day  column. like 17/01/2023 should only  be highlighted today. thanks :)

Comment: You only want it to work for today?: =(C2>=$B2)*(B$1=TODAY()) - this way you're telling it to look in the first row of the corresponding column considered

Comment: I got it , one has to add another condition as c$2 = today().

Comment: Great  @SrikumarSubramanian - considering row 2 being your actual header it's correct!

Answer (score 0):

if you are selecting whole range (`C2:Z`), try this for green and red respectively:

```
=(C2>=$B2)*(C2<>"")
```

---

```
=(C2<$B2)*(C2<>"")
```

- 

[image]